# How to iterate through JSON encoded object in php using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get to my data that came from php using:

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

when I comment out datatype: 'json' I can see normally encoded json string, but when I use it alert shows me array of objects. When I try to get the length of that object array I get 1, but it should be over 20 items in there. I tried doing search posts on here and tried different things iterating through json and none of that works for me for some reason. And I am using

```
mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8");
```

before my select statement on php side. here is my ajax call:

```
function search() {
    $.ajax(
    {
      url: "getFiles.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      type: "POST",
      data: {Filter: $("#txtSearch").val()},
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      success: function(data)
      {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, val)
          {
            alert(val.iddocuments);
            alert(val.docName);
            alert(val.fileName);
            alert(val.fl1);  
            alert(val.dateModified);   
          });   
      }
    });         
  }
```

Comment: can show response.

Comment: Can you show us what `echo json_encode($rows);` gives you

Comment: You could use Firebug (press F12), the Network tab, to see what is coming from the server

Comment: it depends if i use datatype : 'json' or not if i use it  i see [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]..... if not i see [[{"idocuments":66","docName":"name".....

Comment: f12 returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [[{"iddocuments":"66","docName":"(SE)Hardwood Edge Doors","fileName":"(SE)Hardwood Edge Doors.pdf","p21":"","dateModified":"2016-03-17"},{"iddocuments":"67","docName":"1-34 HC Molded Sku's","fileName":"1-34 HC Molded Skus.pdf","p21":"-","dateModified":"2016-03-17"},{"iddocuments":"68","docName":"15% Rush","fileName":"15Rush.pdf","p21":"-","dateModified":"2016-03-17"},{"iddocuments":"69","docName":"20-90min CAT-A","fileName":"20-90min CAT-A.pdf","p21":"","dateModified":"2016-03-17"},...

Comment: if you use `dataType: 'json'`, then the `data` variable should be already parsed as an JavaScript array, so you don't need to parse it again with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I understand, still i cant get to my data even without the JSON.parse I cant access object Object array

Comment: add `dataType: 'json'`, then put a `console.log(data);` statement in `success` function and tell me what it is shown in console tab, in Firebug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134507/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-pavel-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be with the structure of the array that you serialize to json format. Check, with `var_dump($rows)` in PHP to see the exact structure and this structure should match the structure used on the client (in the JavaScript code).

On the client side you could do some debugging to see exactly the structure of what you are receiving, for example with a call to `console.log(data)`, in the `success` function.
In any situation, on the server side, you must add the header `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and on the client side add `dataType: 'json',` so that jQuery knows how to parse the data and make available to you as an JavaScript array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on the PHP side with your use of json_encode():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Referencing the function definition: "string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth = 512 ]] )", the following:

```
<?php
echo "Associative array always output as object: ", json_encode($d), "\n";
echo "Associative array always output as object: ", json_encode($d, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), "\n\n";
?>
```

will output this:

```
Associative array always output as object: {"foo":"bar","baz":"long"}
Associative array always output as object: {"foo":"bar","baz":"long"}
```

JSON_FORCE_OBJECT (integer)
Outputs an object rather than an array when a non-associative array is used. Especially useful when the recipient of the output is expecting an object and the array is empty. Available since PHP 5.3.0.

A similar, "shorthand" version would be:

```
json_encode($d, true);
```

It's also worth mentioning that you should be setting the correct output headers before echoing your output data:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

**Ultimately**, if you're using PHP 5.4 or newer (which you *should* be), implementing the [JsonSerializable Interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) is the best option, as it allows for much more flexible representation of your data from a JSON standpoint.

Comment: where do you post that code header('Content-Type: application/json'); is it inside index.php?

Comment: You would place that before
    echo json_encode($rows, true);